# How to get value of select dropdown which is inside a table cell

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I have a table (using dataTables plugin).  There is a column that has a dropdown `select` element in each row, with several `options`.  In another cell, there is a `submit` button (in each row).  It is represented by an `<a href />` tag in the cell, though the actual submit is made via an AJAX call that uses POST instead of the default GET of an href.

I am attempting to retrieve the value of the selected item in the dropdown when the submit button for that row is clicked.  However, in my java console it just returns [object Object].

It is worth noting that I am trying to work around the fact that each select dropdown has the same ID.

Here is the code for the dropdown select row:

```
<form:select path="adminReviewsLetterStatus.id" id="statusID"><form:option value="">' + full.statusDescriptionState + '</form:option>

<form:options items="${statusList}" itemLabel="statusDescription" itemValue="id"/></form:select>
```

Then, I am attempting to grab the value of that dropdown using the following javascript:

```
var dropDownValue = $(this).prev($("#statusID").find('option:selected').val());
```

(the submit button is in the cell immediately following the cell with the dropdown select).

For the submit button, I use the following:

```
<a href="addLetterToRev.htm?letRevTypYrID=' + full.reviewTypeID + '&letterId=' + full.id + '&statusIdParameter=' + dropDownValue + '" title="Add">Add</a>
```

(Where `statusIdParameter` is the parameter that I grab in my controller).

When I print to my java console, I get the expected values for the `letRevTypYrID` and `letterId` parameters, but my `statusIdParameter` parameter returns `[object Object]`.

I feel like I am close to getting this thing to work, so any advice is greatly appreciated.

The AJAX call is pretty simple:

```
$.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        method: 'POST'
});

    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

`var dropDownValue = $(this).prev($("#statusID").find('option:selected').val());`

`$.prev()` returns a DOM element, which is the `object` you're getting. As you can see you're var is getting filled with whatever comes out of `$.prev()`.

Instead do this:

`var dropDownValue = $(this).prev(),find("#statusID").val();`

`$.prev()` should get the cell with the dropdown according to your question. Find will get the dropdown, then `$.val()` works on the `select` element, which is filled with the selected option (so don't use `$.val()` on an `option` element.

Also, you should fill the url in the ajax statement, not by using the `href` attribute in your `<a />`, it will create confusion for you this way when you look back at your code (even though it works fine).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However, this is returning "undefined" for me.

Comment: It's probably because there's a selector going wrong somewhere. You need to figure that out yourself, OR post your html and javascript, because I can't help you further without seeing what Im programming against.